How do you reference a model name in a Django model mixin field definition?
How do you reference the model name in field definition in a model mixin? Ie, what would replace model_name here:
class CreatedByMixin(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created_by = ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name="Created by",
        help_text="User that created the record",
        related_name=f"{model_name}_created",
        editable=False,
    )

Such that the related name on this model is 'MyModel_created'?
class MyModel(UserAuditMixin, TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table_comment = "Participants are the users that are involved in the transcript"

    field1 = models.TextField()


You are looking for %(class)s [Django-doc]. You don't format the string in the ForeignKey: Django automatically (re)formats the string, so you use:
class CreatedByMixin(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created_by = ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name='Created by',
        help_text='User that created the record',
        related_name='%(class)s_created',
        editable=False,
    )
